# Binary OR Operator

Tags: java, operator-keyword, bitwise-operators

Hello I have two numbers

```
int a= 6;
int b = 20;
```

when I am doing `or` i.e. `|` operation it is not giving the correct result.

```
int result = a | b ;
```

`result = 22` but the correct answer is `26`.

Comment: Why do you think the correct answer is 26 ?

Comment: 6 = 4 + 2 ; 20 = 4 + 16 - the 4 is only counted once in the |

Comment: yes correct answer is 26

Comment: If you want 26 as a result, why don't you use simple + operator ?

Comment: No, the correct answer is 22, not 26.

Comment: It's very unlikely that something so simple as the | operator would actually be broken. Compilers have bugs, but not of that kind - it would be noticed immediately.

Answer (score 5):

22 is correct :

```
6     is  0..000110
20    is  0..010100
6|20  is  0..010110 which is 22
```

If you do the operation using HEX numbers and convert the result to HEX, you'll get 26 (in HEX) :

```
int a= 0x6; int b = 0x20;
int result = a | b ;
System.out.println (Integer.toString (result,16));
```

Comment: but when you are doing on calculator (programming mode) it is giving 26

Comment: @Rohitesh Addition and bitwise OR are two different operators.

Comment: @Jack if you will convet 20 into binary you will get 0010 0000 how yours comming 0..010100

Comment: @Rohitesh `0010 0000` is not 20. It's 32.

Comment: @Rohitesh: Ummm... no. 20 is `0 * 2**0 + 0 * 2**1 + 1 * 2**2 + 0 * 2**3 + 1 * 2**4` or `0..010100` (reading the places in decreasing order). `0010 0000` is `2**5` or 32.

Comment: @Rohitesh: Aaaand what does that link have to do with the problem at hand? That's a tool that converts hex to binary. That has absolutely nothing to do with the binary or operator.

Comment: @Rohitesh That link converts from HEX to Binary. Yes, 20 in Hex is 00100000 in binary (and 32 in decimal).

Comment: ya my numbers are in hex format only and when i use that tool to convert 20 hexa to binary it is giving me 0010 0000 i am confused sorry ....

Comment: @Rohitesh: When you declare `int b = 20;` in Java, the compiler takes `20` in base 10, not base 16.

Comment: ok...thanks so can you plz tell me how to do 6 | 20 operation so that i can get 26 as result

Comment: @Rohitesh You'll have to initialize a and b with HEX literals. See edited answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot its working but cannot we do like                                                                                                             int num = 10;
int hexNum = 0xnum;                                                                     because my numbers are generating dynamically

Comment: @Rohitesh: Ummm...no.

Comment: seems u r taking input in HEX not in DEC

Comment: any solution for this can i add the two numbers at the end it is giving me the same value

Comment: @Rohitesh What do you mean? Did you try the code I suggested? That would print 26.

Comment: @Earn yes i tried your code its working for static value i.e. int a= 0x6; but if i need 6 value to be replaced every time then i have to put some varivable there int a = 0xvariable but this is not working

Comment: @Rohitesh So what's the problem? If you want to get the input from a user, get the input as a String and call `Integer.parseInt(str,16)` in order to treat that input as a HEX number. This way you'll be able to type in 20, and it will be converted to 32 by parseInt.

Comment: @Earn its not working  int num = randomNumber; int a = 0xnum; please can you edit in your answer.I am not able to do this

Comment: @Rohitesh You can't do that. When you have an `int` variable, it's neither decimal nor HEX. It's 32 bits. You can't print that number as a decimal number (that's the default) or as HEX (or other bases) number, but if you want to initialize it with a HEX input, either use a HEX literal such as 0x20, or parseInt(str,16) for some String that contains the HEX representation of the number. If you write `int num=20;`, 20 will be treated as a decimal number. If you want to later convert that number to HEX, you can convert it to String and then parseInt : `Integer.parseInt(Integer.toString (num),16)`.